# SSRS Grouping multiple tables based on Multi Value parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, grouping, multivalue

I have a report containing seven tables, each table returning a different set of values for a list of id's selected in a parameter list. I have the tables enclosed in a rectangle so that they print together.

Now I would like to group the results based on the id passed in from the multi-select parameter. So if I have a list of four ids in my parameter list the report would  displaying my rectangle of seven tables four times, one for each id.

What would be the best way to do this?

Should I take my rectangle of seven tables and enclose it in another table grouped on the id? Or place it in a list item?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can add grouping on the rectangle on `Parameters!<ParameterName>.Value` which is an array of values.

Then, per table you need to define this group as the parent and SSRS should then pass the grouping ID to the tables in each rectangle/id grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list control.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

SORT FILENAME BY-EXP multivalueDict BREAK-ON MultivalueDict OtherValue1 OtherValue2 etc...

Comment: What is this meant to be please?